# Im trying to query a portion of the mongofb document

Tags: mongodb, go

***I'm trying to just get a lobby by whatever ID passed, but it's returning to me no document in result.***

I don't know any other approach I can use for this.

This is the function to get the lobby ID and decode it into the model.Lobby struct, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct btw

```
func CheckLobbyID(lobbyID string) (model.Lobby, error) {
    filter := bson.M{"lobby_id": lobbyID}
    var lobby model.Lobby
    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 10*time.Second)
    err := AttendanceCollection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&lobby)
    defer cancel()
    if err != nil {
        return model.Lobby{}, err
    }
    return lobby, nil
}
```

This is the data struct and it's how the data is represented in the database.

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type Attendance struct {
    ID   primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Day1 Lobbies
    Day2 Lobbies
    Day3 Lobbies
    Day4 Lobbies
    Day5 Lobbies
}

type Lobbies struct {
    DayNumber int    `json:"day_number,omitempty" bson:"day_number,omitempty"`
    Date      string `json:"date,omitempty" bson:"date,omitempty"`
    Lobby1    Lobby
    Lobby2    Lobby
    Lobby3    Lobby
}

type Lobby struct {
    LobbyID   string `json:"lobby_id,omitempty" bson:"lobby_id,omitempty"`
    Player1   *Player
    Player2   *Player
    Player3   *Player
    Player4   *Player
    UpdatedAt string `json:"updated_at,omitempty" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

type Player struct {
    PlayerCode int    `json:"layer_code,omitempty" bson:"player_code,omitempty"`
    PlayerID   string `json:"player_id,omitempty" bson:"player_id,omitempty"`
    Name       string `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Kills      int    `json:"kills,omitempty" bson:"kills,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    UpdatedAt  string `json:"updated_at,omitempty" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

type KillCount struct {
    Kills int `json:"kills,omitempty" validate:"required"`
}
```

This is another method I tried in using to query the lobby with it id, but it just returns a lobby with the players `null` instead of returning the players in the lobby.

```
func CheckLobbyID(lobbyID string) (model.Lobby, error) {
var filters = []bson.M{}
numDays := 5
numLobbies := 3
for dayNum := 1; dayNum <= numDays; dayNum++ {
    for lobbyNum := 1; lobbyNum <= numLobbies; lobbyNum++ {
        filterCondition := bson.M{
            fmt.Sprintf("day%v.lobby%v.lobby_id", dayNum, lobbyNum): lobbyID,
        }
        filters = append(filters, filterCondition)
    }
}

pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {
        {
            "$match", bson.M{
                "$or": filters,
            },
        },
    },
}

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

cursor, err := AttendanceCollection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
defer cancel()
if err != nil {
    return model.Lobby{}, err
}

var results []model.Lobby
defer cursor.Close(ctx)
for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    var res model.Lobby
    cursor.Decode(&res)
    results = append(results, res)
}

if len(results) == 0 {
    return model.Lobby{}, errors.New("no Lobby with provided ID found")
}

var lobby model.Lobby

for _, result := range results {
    lobby = result
}
return lobby, nil
```

}

Comment: Your `Attendance` documents have no `lobby_id` field, so filtering to that will result in no documents. You want a filter where `"Lobby1.lobby_id"` or `"Lobby2.lobby_id"` etc. matches the value, I assume. This isn't very practical, you'd better store lobbies in an array, so you can form a single `lobbies.lobby_id` filter that will result in documents where any of the lobbies have the matching ID. Also move `defer cancel()` call right after context creation (above the query).